# PHP Search Function prints all records, not those searched for

Tags: php, sql, search

I've just created a very simple search function in PHP, but am having a few issues. The search function sends a query to the database, and prints results, but it doesn't print the results I want. It's supposed to print those records that are like the user input, but it just prints every record.

My Form is as follows:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
     <input  type="text" name="name"> 
     <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"> 
</form>
```

And the PHP code to make it search is:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    { 
     require ('mysqli_connect.php');
     include ('config.php');

    $term = $_POST['term'];
        $q = "SELECT  name, producer, jamtypes, user FROM Jam WHERE name LIKE '%" . $term .  "%'";
        $sql = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

        echo "<br />";
         echo 'Name: '.$row['name'];
         echo '<br/> Producer: '.$row['producer'];
         echo '<br/> Created By: '.$row['user'];
         echo '<br/> Category: '.$row['jamtypes'];
         echo '<br/>';

        }
  }
```

Thanks guys

Comment: You're wide open to sql injections

Comment: `echo $q;` is it what you expected? there is no "term" in your form, perhaps you wanted "name"

Comment: John is correct World, you should sanitize your database inputs. Mysqli offers prepared statements which helps this [http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php]http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Changing `$term = $_POST['term'];` to `$term = $_POST['name'];` could help to solve your problem

Comment: Cheers for the warning guys. Was planning on testing the security side of things once I'd got it working :) Apoligies for the idiocy of the question, should have worked it out myself really!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form field is `name`, not `term`, so your PHP should be

```
$term = $_POST['name'];
```

Because `$term` is blank due to having an incorrect value your query returns all results. (Your query looks like `SELECT  name, producer, jamtypes, user FROM Jam WHERE name LIKE '%&'`)

FYI, having error_reporting turned on and reporting notices would have told you this. Always develop with error reporting on and displaying all errors.

Comment: Thanks! Really simple, stupid error. I did have term in my form previously, but took it out and re-did the php. Should have error checked it, and will do in future. Cheers again.